# Multiple Build Folders (multiple clients, mulitask, multiple targets) using Grunt (Yeoman)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, gruntjs, yeoman

I am building a project right now that will be a webapp (browser runnable) and a Phonegap app (iOS & Android). Although my project, theoretically, could use the same `dist` folder that my **[Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)** generated, **[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)** tasks `build` production ready code by running `grunt build`. I would like to run something like `grunt build_web`, `grunt build_ios`, and `grunt build_android`, to build out production code for each platform individually. Or `grunt build:web`, `grunt build:ios`, `grunt build:android`. This way, I could customize some of the loaded scripts, images, etc each with their own build directives.

<strike>So, should I go through my Gruntfile copying and pasting all of by `dist` and `build` directives responsibly? Or, is there a best practice for this?</strike> (tried this, didn't work)

Yeoman folks, is this possible?

Here is my current **Gruntfile.js** in case it would be useful to see.

```
'use strict';
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;
var lrSnippet = require('connect-livereload')({port: LIVERELOAD_PORT});
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // show elapsed time at the end
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);
    // load all grunt tasks
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // configurable paths
    var yeomanConfig = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: '../www'
    };

    grunt.initConfig({
        yeoman: yeomanConfig,
        watch: {
            coffee: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
                tasks: ['coffee:dist']
            },
            coffeeTest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
                tasks: ['coffee:test']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            lrSnippet,
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, 'test'),
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.dist)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        open: {
            server: {
                path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
            }
        },
        clean: {
            options: {
                force: true
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        mocha: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    run: true,
                    urls: ['http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>/index.html']
                }
            }
        },
        coffee: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                    src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
                    dest: '.tmp/scripts',
                    ext: '.js'
                }]
            },
            test: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'test/spec',
                    src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
                    dest: '.tmp/spec',
                    ext: '.js'
                }]
            }
        },
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
                importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
                httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
                }
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true
                }
            }
        },
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },
        // not used since Uglify task does concat,
        // but still available if needed
        /*concat: {
            dist: {}
        },*/
        requirejs: {
            dist: {
                // Options: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js
                options: {
                    // `name` and `out` is set by grunt-usemin
                    baseUrl: yeomanConfig.app + '/scripts',
                    optimize: 'none',
                    // TODO: Figure out how to make sourcemaps work with grunt-usemin
                    // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/30
                    //generateSourceMaps: true,
                    // required to support SourceMaps
                    // http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#sourcemapcomments
                    preserveLicenseComments: false,
                    useStrict: true,
                    wrap: true
                    //uglify2: {} // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2
                }
            }
        },
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        useminPrepare: {
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            },
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
        },
        usemin: {
            options: {
                dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
            },
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            // This task is pre-configured if you do not wish to use Usemin
            // blocks for your CSS. By default, the Usemin block from your
            // `index.html` will take care of minification, e.g.
            //
            //     <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
            //
            // dist: {
            //     files: {
            //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
            //             '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            //             '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
            //         ]
            //     }
            // }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                    //collapseWhitespace: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true*/
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    src: '*.html',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },
        // Put files not handled in other tasks here
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },
        modernizr: {
            devFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
            outputFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
            ],
            uglify: true
        },
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'compass',
                'coffee:dist',
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
                'coffee',
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
                'coffee',
                'compass',
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin',
                'htmlmin'
            ]
        },
        bower: {
            options: {
                exclude: ['modernizr']
            },
            all: {
                rjsConfig: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/main.js'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'open',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:test',
        'mocha'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'requirejs',
        'concat',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'modernizr',
        'copy:dist',
        'rev',
        'usemin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: Thx for posting your file. I didn't get the modernizr-devFile option. Now it works! :P

Answer (score 3):

There's really no best practice out there beside what's recommended for PG 3.  For multiple clients, you may want to modify your gruntjs.  This is my project structure, where assets folder contain data for different clients:

[image]

And here is my gruntjs file.  It use ImageMagik to create all the necessary launcher icons.  Build and deploy for over the air installation.  You get the idea...

```
/***
 * Package script for MobileStore
 ***/

'use strict';

// require package.json:
/*
{
  "name": "MobileStore",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-exec": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-string-replace": "~0.2.4",
    "grunt-image-resize": "~0.2.0"
  }
}
*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var isMacOS = grunt.file.isDir('/etc');

    // load all grunt tasks
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // configurable paths
    var myConfig = {
        dest: 'out/',
        platforms: ['ios', 'android'], 
        chains: [11,52,75,119,129,224,229,235],
        chainConfig: {},
        baseDir: __dirname + '/'
    };
    var chainid = grunt.option('chainid');
    if (chainid) {
        myConfig.chains = [chainid];
    }

    // set up grunt
    var gruntConfig = {
        clean: {
          build: ['out', 'beta-assets']
        },
        copy: {},
        exec: {},
        "string-replace": {},
        image_resize: {}
    };

    // first thing to do is clean
    var packageConfig = ['clean'];

    // duplicate source to the chain
    // copy from platforms/(android/ios) to out/chainid/(android/ios)
    myConfig.chains.forEach(function(chain) {
        myConfig.platforms.forEach(function(platform) {
            var key = 'setup_' + platform + chain;

            // any platform is fine, we're just preping chainConfig
            if (platform == 'android')
            {
                myConfig.chainConfig[chain] = require('./YourCompany.Mobile/assets/' + chain + '/build.json');
            }

            gruntConfig.copy[key] = {
                files: [
                  {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'YourCompany.Mobile/platforms/' + platform + '/', 
                    src: ['./**'], 
                    dest: 'out/' + chain + '/' + platform + '/'
                  }
                ]
            };

            packageConfig.push('copy:' + key);
        });
    });

    // override the device resource (icon, splash, etc..)
    // copy from assets/chainid/device/(android/ios) to out/chainid/(android/ios)
    myConfig.chains.forEach(function(chain) {
        myConfig.platforms.forEach(function(platform) {
            var key = 'device_resource_' + platform + chain;
            var srcArt = 'YourCompany.Mobile/assets/' + chain + '/device/AndroidArtwork.png';

            var dest = 'out/' + chain + '/' + platform + '/MobileStore/';
            if (platform == 'android') 
            {
                dest += 'res/';
            }
            else if (platform == 'ios') {
                dest += 'MobileStore/';
            }

            gruntConfig.copy[key] = {
                files: [
                  {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'YourCompany.Mobile/assets/' + chain + '/device/' + platform + '/', 
                    src: ['./**'], 
                    dest: dest
                  }
                ]
            };

            packageConfig.push('copy:' + key);

            // do image manipulations
            // Use AnroidArtwork.png
            if (platform == 'android') {
                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_36'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 36,     
                            height: 36,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest  + 'drawable-ldpi/icon.png'
                        }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_36');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_48'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 48, 
                            height: 48,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest  + 'drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
                        }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_48');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_72'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 72, 
                            height: 72,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest  + 'drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
                        }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_72');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_96'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 96,  
                            height: 96,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest  + 'drawable-xhdpi/icon.png'
                        }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_96');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_default'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 96,  
                            height: 96,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest + 'drawable/icon.png'
                        }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_default');
            }
            else if (platform == 'ios') {
                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_57'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 57,  
                            height: 57,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest + 'Resources/icons/Icon.png'
                        }]
                };

                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_57');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_114'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 114,  
                            height: 114,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest + 'Resources/icons/Icon@2x.png'
                        }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_114');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_72'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 72, 
                            height: 72,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest + 'Resources/icons/Icon-72.png'
                        }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_72');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_144'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 144,  
                            height: 144,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest + 'Resources/icons/Icon-72@2x.png'
                        }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_144');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_29'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 29,  
                            height: 29,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest + 'Resources/icons/Icon-Small.png'
                        }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_29');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_58'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 58, 
                            height: 58,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest  + 'Resources/icons/Icon-Small@2x.png'
                        }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_58');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_50'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 50,  
                            height: 50,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest  + 'Resources/icons/Icon-Small-50.png'
                        }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_50');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_100'] = {
                        options: {
                            width: 100,   
                            height: 100,
                            overwrite: true
                        },
                        files: [{
                            src: srcArt,
                            dest: dest  + 'Resources/icons/Icon-Small-50@2x.png'
                        }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_100');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_1024'] = {
                    options: {
                        width: 1024,
                        height: 1024,
                        overwrite: true,
                        upscale: true
                    },
                    files: [{
                        src: srcArt,
                        dest: dest + 'Resources/iTunesArtwork'
                    }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_1024');

                // setup images for ota deploy
                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_512x'] = {
                    options: {
                        width: 512,
                        height: 512,
                        overwrite: true,
                        upscale: true
                    },
                    files: [{
                        src: srcArt,
                        dest: dest + '../iTunesArtwork.png'
                    }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_512x');

                gruntConfig.image_resize[key + '_57x'] = {
                    options: {
                        width: 57,
                        height: 57,
                        overwrite: true
                    },
                    files: [{
                        src: srcArt,
                        dest: dest + '../Icon.png'
                    }]
                };
                packageConfig.push('image_resize:' + key + '_57x');
            }
        });
    });

    // copy assets to www folder
    // copy from www to out/chainid/...
    myConfig.chains.forEach(function(chain) {
        myConfig.platforms.forEach(function(platform) {
            var key = 'content_' + platform + chain;
            var dest = 'out/' + chain + '/' + platform + '/MobileStore/';
            if (platform == 'android') 
            {
                dest += 'assets/www/';
            }
            else if (platform == 'ios') {
                dest += 'www/';
            }

            gruntConfig.copy[key] = {
                files: [
                  {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'YourCompany.Mobile/www/', 
                    src: ['./**'], 
                    dest: dest
                  }
                ]
            };

            packageConfig.push('copy:' + key);
        });
    });

    // copy assets override
    // copy from assets/chainid/www to out/chainid/...
    myConfig.chains.forEach(function(chain) {
        myConfig.platforms.forEach(function(platform) {
            var key = 'content_override_' + platform + chain;
            var dest = 'out/' + chain + '/' + platform + '/MobileStore/';
            if (platform == 'android') 
            {
                dest += 'assets/www/';
            }
            else if (platform == 'ios') {
                dest += 'www/';
            }

            gruntConfig.copy[key] = {
                files: [
                  {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'YourCompany.Mobile/assets/' + chain + '/www/', 
                    src: ['./**'], 
                    dest: dest
                  }
                ]
            };

            packageConfig.push('copy:' + key);
        });
    });

    // copy phonegap merges
    // copy from merges to out/chainid/...
    myConfig.chains.forEach(function(chain) {
        myConfig.platforms.forEach(function(platform) {
            var key = 'phonegap_override_' + platform + chain;
            var dest = 'out/' + chain + '/' + platform + '/MobileStore/';
            if (platform == 'android') 
            {
                dest += 'assets/www/';
            }
            else if (platform == 'ios') {
                dest += 'www/';
            }

            gruntConfig.copy[key] = {
                files: [
                  {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'YourCompany.Mobile/merges/' + platform, 
                    src: ['./**'], 
                    dest: dest
                  }
                ]
            };

            packageConfig.push('copy:' + key);
        });
    });

    // doing beta assets deployment
    myConfig.chains.forEach(function (chain) {
        var key = 'content_beta_assets_' + chain;
        var src = 'out/' + chain + '/ios/MobileStore/www/';

        gruntConfig.copy[key] = {
            files: [
              {
                  expand: true,
                  cwd: src,
                  src: ['./**'],
                  dest: 'beta-assets/' + chain + '/www/'
              }
            ]
        };

        packageConfig.push('copy:' + key);

        // override cordova file
        gruntConfig.copy[key + '_pg'] = {
            files: [
              {
                  expand: true,
                  cwd: 'YourCompany.Mobile/www/',
                  src: ['./cordova.js'],
                  dest: 'beta-assets/' + chain + '/www/'
              }
            ]
        };

        packageConfig.push('copy:' + key + '_pg');

    });

    // doing android(ant) build
    myConfig.chains.forEach(function (chain) {
        var key = 'android_build_' + chain;

        var dest = 'out/' + chain + '/android/MobileStore/';
        var destFolder = './out/' + chain + '/';
        // use previous chainConfig to perform text replace
        gruntConfig["string-replace"][key + '_prep'] = {
            files: [
                  {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'out/' + chain + '/', 
                    src: ['./**/**.java', './**/**.xml', './**/**.plist', './**/**.m'],
                    dest: 'out/' + chain + '/'
                  }
            ],
            options: {
              replacements: [
                {
                    pattern: /(net.yourcompany.MobileStore)+/ig,
                    replacement: myConfig.chainConfig[chain].id
                },
                {
                    pattern: /(AppleBundleSeedID)+/ig,
                    replacement: myConfig.chainConfig[chain].AppleBundleSeedID
                },
                {   pattern: '<string name="app_name">MobileStore</string>',
                    replacement: '<string name="app_name">' + myConfig.chainConfig[chain].ApplicationName + '</string>'
                }
              ]
            }
        };

        packageConfig.push('string-replace:' + key + '_prep');

        // do build
        gruntConfig.exec[key] = {
            cmd: 'ant clean && ant debug',
            cwd: dest,
            env: process.env
        };

        packageConfig.push('exec:' + key);

    });

    // doing xcode build
    myConfig.chains.forEach(function(chain) {
        var key = 'ios_build_' + chain;
        var chainConfig = myConfig.chainConfig[chain];
        var dest = myConfig.baseDir + 'out/' + chain + '/ios/MobileStore/';
        var buildDir = dest + 'Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/';
        var commandStart = 'export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/Shared/ImageMagick-6.8.6:$PATH" &&'
        var command = 'chmod 777 dobuild && ./dobuild "' + chainConfig.AppleProductName + '" ' + chain + ' ' + process.env.BUILD_NUMBER + ' "' + chainConfig.AppleBundleSeedID + '.' + chainConfig.id + '"';
        grunt.log.debug('ios build:' + command);

        if (isMacOS) {
            gruntConfig.exec[key] = {
                cmd: command,
                cwd: dest,
                exitCode: 0
            };
            packageConfig.push('exec:' + key);
        }

        // prep apk for deployment
        gruntConfig.copy['android_build_' + chain + '_apk'] = {
            options: {
                processContent: false
            },
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    src: ['out/' + chain + '/android/MobileStore/bin/MobileStore-debug.apk'],
                    dest: 'beta-assets/' + chain + '/',
                    filter: 'isFile'
                }
            ]
        };

        packageConfig.push('copy:' + 'android_build_' + chain + '_apk');

        // prep ipa for ios deploy
        gruntConfig.copy['ios_build_' + chain + '_ipa'] = {
            options: {
                processContent: false
            },
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    src: ['out/' + chain + '/ios/MobileStore/Build/**.ipa'],
                    dest: 'beta-assets/' + chain + '/',
                    filter: 'isFile'
                }
            ]
        };

        packageConfig.push('copy:' + 'ios_build_' + chain + '_ipa');

        // drop plist
        gruntConfig.copy['ios_build_' + chain + '_plist'] = {
            options: {
                processContent: false
            },
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    src: ['out/' + chain + '/ios/MobileStore/Build/**.plist'],
                    dest: 'beta-assets/' + chain + '/',
                    filter: 'isFile'
                }
            ]
        };

        packageConfig.push('copy:' + 'ios_build_' + chain + '_plist');

        // drop html
        gruntConfig.copy['ios_build_' + chain + '_html'] = {
            options: {
                processContent: false
            },
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    src: ['out/' + chain + '/ios/MobileStore/Build/install.html'],
                    dest: 'beta-assets/' + chain + '/',
                    filter: 'isFile'
                }
            ]
        };

        packageConfig.push('copy:' + 'ios_build_' + chain + '_html');

        // drop png
        gruntConfig.copy['ios_build_' + chain + '_png'] = {
            options: {
                processContent: false
            },
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    src: ['out/' + chain + '/ios/MobileStore/*.png'],
                    dest: 'beta-assets/' + chain + '/',
                    filter: 'isFile'
                }
            ]
        };

        packageConfig.push('copy:' + 'ios_build_' + chain + '_png');
    });


    grunt.initConfig(gruntConfig);
    grunt.registerTask('package', packageConfig);

    // Default task.
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'package');
};
```

Basically, it drop all the native and merges into out/clientorchainid folder to do the build for each client.  Then it copy the build result into beta-assets/clientorchainid folder to prep for remote deployment.

Comment: Although, this may work. I am looking for something that is specific to Yeoman. Perhaps my question isn't specific enough to warrant a Yeoman specific response. Thank you for your help, though. I will do my best to wade through it and see what insight I can glean.

Comment: Well, I also run Yeoman, but that is not my build process for multi-client native output.  My project started out with Yeoman to generate the application but I since converted it to Visual Studio 2012 because my developers are more familiar with that environment.  I still do all my unit tests and code minification in Yeoman with the expectation that we may be able to reuse the code for the mobile website and not just for native PhoneGap.

Answer (score 2):

Build is a list of other tasks. You could do something like this (coffescript):

```
grunt.registerTask "build", [
    "clean:dist",
    "jade:html",
    "clientTemplates",
    "useminPrepare",
    "concurrent:dist",
    "copy:prerequire",
    "requirejs",
    "cssmin",
    "concat",
    "uglify",
    "copy:dist",
    "rev",
    "usemin"
]
```

That way you can deifne custom tasks and custom builds, etc.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I understand that I could copy the build task, and create a build2 task. Because some of the tasks within build **don't support [Multi-Tasks](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets)**, there is a problem. I have moved on, for now, in favor of running **[multiple Gruntfiles](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18468938/998352)**.