# Grunt/Yeoman Multiple Gruntfile.js Files

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

My goal is the be able to build my project to two separate build folders, each with its' own Grunt tasks.

I noticed the `grunt-cli` has the `--gruntfile` option which allows you to specify another Gruntfile to use. So far, I have a `Gruntfile.js` working perfectly (near stock from Yeoman). Also, I have another `Gruntfile2.js` sitting alongside.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
var yeomanConfig = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: '../www_browser'
};
```

**Gruntfile2.js**

```
var yeomanConfig = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: '../www'
};
```

`grunt build` is meant to run Gruntfile.js, and does so perfectly.

`grunt build --gruntfile Gruntfile2.js` is meant to run `Gruntfile2.js`, and does so with some hiccups. (supposed to build to `../www` folder NOT `../www_browser` folder)

The --gruntfile directive builds to the proper folder for almost every task except **grunt-usemin** and **gunt-contrib-htmlmin**. I know this because of this output to the console here:

```
Running "usemin:css" (usemin) task
Processing as CSS - ../www_browser/styles/22f60055.main.css

Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task

Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task
File ../www_browser/404.html created.
File ../www_browser/index.html created.
```

You'll notice the **../www_browser**, here in console output. Every other task runs in the expected **../www** folder.

Is this a usemin cache thing? Grunt cache thing? Or do some tasks simply run from the default Gruntfile.js regardless of the `--gruntfile Gruntfile2.js` directive?

I have given up on trying to do multiple targets from a single Gruntfile for now. There are too many dependencies in Yeoman's Gruntfile.js that don't yet support multiple build targets, and I spent 12 hours to no avail with that approach.

**Version Info**

```
$: grunt --version
grunt-cli v0.1.9
grunt v0.4.1

$: npm --version
1.2.25

$: yo --version
1.0.3
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.6.5",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-bower-requirejs": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.10",
    "grunt-mocha": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.1.0",
    "matchdep": "~0.1.1",
    "connect-livereload": "~0.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be reading the default Gruntfile. As an experiment, have you tried removing, or renaming the default Gruntfile.js to something random before running `grunt build --gruntfile Gruntfile2.js`?

Comment: Good suggestion. This one is going to lead me down another rabbit hole. Now getting error for concurrent:dist task  Warning: A valid Gruntfile could not be found. Please see the getting started guide for
    more information on how to configure grunt: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
    Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile.

Comment: This is documented here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/issues/26

Although, after reverting back to grunt-cli v0.1.8 I am receiving the same error.

Comment: UPDATE: This seems to be a problem with grunt-concurrent task. Please see https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent/issues/17 for further correspondence. Once, I get this resolved, I'll be back for solution.

Comment: Looks like you're making progress, although I doubt the issue is with the concurrent task, as i've just tried it myself and it works as expected with a custom Gruntfile. Can you post your package.json file?

Comment: Sure, see edit to question. Also, did you see the entire issue I filed on GitHub? Particularly the part where I say, "BTW, when I remove concurrent:dist from build task, and replace with tasks that should be run concurrently, it works as expected."

Comment: I've added my answer to the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using an older version of grunt-concurrent, which doesn't seem to be passing the grunt flags through to the child-processes.

See here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent/blob/v0.1.0/tasks/concurrent.js#L11

On the current version of the plugin, the flags are passed, see here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent/blob/v0.3.1/tasks/concurrent.js#L22

So, I suggest updating your version of grunt-concurrent:

`npm install grunt-concurrent@latest --save-dev`